# Executable path to Mac App

Tags: python, macos, py2app

In a py2app/Mac Application Bundle, is there a way to spawn another instance of same app from within the app, by passing different command line arguments?

or given a mac app bundle, how can I run it from command line and pass some arguments too?

Edit1:forking is a limited option, which may not work with 3rd party executables bundle with app+I need to run this on mac and windows.
Edit2: **Question is how to run a a bundled python script using subprocess module**

### Details:

I am using py2app to generate a app bundle for my appilcation. My application has two parts

1. MainApp: which is the UI
2. BackgroundApp: a background process, which does the real job

Both MainApp and BackgroundApp have been implemented as python script and actually they are the same python script with different commandline e.g.

```
python myapp.py
python myapp.py --backgroundprocess
```

So when I run `python myapp.py` it automatically starts background process based on program path, but as I have now bundled my app as py2app I am not sure what executable I should be calling and passing `--backgroundprocess` option?

### What I have tried

1. `$ open MyApp.app/` this opens the app but I can't pass the arguments to it, as they will be arguments for open command and will not be passed to my app
2. `$ MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp --backgroundprocess` opens the app but not the backgroun process as it seems arguments are not being passed to app

also it throws error

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/agyey/projects/myapp/release4.26/py2exe/dist/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/run.py", line 4, in <module>
    from renderprocess import RenderEngineApp
  File "renderprocess/RenderEngineApp.pyc", line 6, in <module>
  File "wx/__init__.pyc", line 45, in <module>
  File "wx/_core.pyc", line 4, in <module>
  File "wx/_core_.pyc", line 18, in <module>
  File "wx/_core_.pyc", line 11, in __load
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/agyey/projects/myapp/release4.26/py2exe/dist/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.5/lib-dynload/wx/_core_.so, 2): Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/libwx_macud-2.8.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/agyey/projects/myapp/release4.26/py2exe/dist/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.5/lib-dynload/wx/_core_.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: _core_.so requires version 7.0.0 or later, but libwx_macud-2.8.0.dylib provides version 2.6.0
```

Conclusion: it looks like it may not be possible
[Launch an app on OS X with command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308755/launch-an-app-on-os-x-with-command-line)

`open` doesn't except arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Howto find cwd and execute an arbitrary supplied binary**
First place the binary in AppName.app/Contents/Resources then run this code from the python script:

```
import subprocess
process=subprocess.Popen((os.getcwd() + "/3rd_party_binary","--subprocess")) 
process.poll() # is running?
```

**Howto properly spawn two version of your python app**

Fork is the old tried way to do this on MacOSX (unix)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, sys

pid = os.fork()
if pid:
    # we are the parent
    background_process.start()
    os.waitpid(pid, 0) # make sure the child process gets cleaned up
else:
    # we are the child
    gui_app.start()
    sys.exit(0)

print "parent: got it; text =", txt
```

[Multiprocessing in Python](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-multiprocessing/) is apparently something that works on windows as well which I guess would be interesting to you(?).

Comment: that is an option, but simpler option would be to just execute it separately because I usually just run background process for testing + I may run different background process at different time on user input, anyway I am more interested to know how can I run my background process or any other app included in bundle without complicating the code

Comment: my question is simply, how to run a a bundled python script using subprocess module

Comment: Well it is possible you just have to figure out how py2app does it, which shouldn't be so hard. You want to run "python AppName.app/Contents/Resources/myapp.py", not the OSX binary.

Comment: Forks are wonderful btw, once you have forked you will never look back.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Create one application then just call the --bakgroundproccess for the app, then create a shortcut for the backgroundprocess flag. Or two different app files. Ether is a good way

Comment: a) i have to call background app from main app, how shortcut will help? b) if I create two app, still how will first app know where is second app, and also how to call a app with arguments?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get py2app working, but the applications' executable are located in `AppName.app/Contents/MacOS/AppName`. You can check in `AppName.app/Contents/Info.plist` file for key `<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>`, it points to the bundles executable in `AppName.app/Contents/MacOS` folder.

So you can call it as `AppName.app/Contents/MacOS/AppName --backgroundprocess`.

If you want the `BackgroundApp` to run the background process without any arguments, there are two options: a) make the bundle from python script, which runs the background process without any arguments; b) change `<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>` in `Info.plist` file to say `BackGroundApp_shell`, and make a shell script `Contents/MacOS/BackgroundApp_shell` of the following content:

```
#!/bin/sh

`dirname "$0"`/BackgroundApp --backgroundprocess
```

assuming the executable is `BackgroundApp`.

Comment: I have already tried something like `AppName.app/Contents/MacOS/AppName --backgroundprocess` but it fails, looks like py2app or mac sets some environment variables before executing the app

Comment: @Anurag you can try to make a bundle for a simple python script: `import sys; print sys.argv` to see how the exec created py2app treats command-line arguments. I don't think this is something concerning env vars. Just a guess: py2app creates an exec which doesn't take arguments, but you can try that simple script, to make sure.